# ldap authorizedkeyscommand failed status 255

Tags: ssh, ldap

I have a user that can't login into one of our Centos7 boxes using his public key from the LDAP server.

The error message that sshd logs (DEBUG mode on) is `error: AuthroizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper userx failed, status 255`.

Running as root `ssh-ldap-wrapper userx` I can confirm that it does connect to the LDAP server and prints out the correct public key for that user.

The permission for the wrapper are 755. We have another Centos7 box where the user can log in without problems. Alas I'm failing to find what is there different.

The config in `sshd_config` is:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AllowGroups groupA groupB
```

and `userx` has been assigned to `groupB` in our LDAP server.

Google only gives hits related to some bugs but I found none that helped -or at least couldn't figure out as of yet how.

What am I missing to set up for the user to be able to log in using his public key stored in our LDAP server?

#### Edit: Additional info

```
# ls -Z /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper
# cat /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-helper -s "$1"
```

The option `-s` requires a username to check against the LDAP server for credentials.

The configuration of the ldap-helper seems to be within `/etc/ssh/ldap.conf`. This contains the following two lines

```
openssh_ldap_loglevel debug
openssh_ldap_logfile /var/log/openssh-ldap.log
```

yet that log file is not even created.

Comment: Where does the "wrapper" itself come from, and does it have any logging options? Can you try running it manually but with `KRB5CCNAME="MEMORY:"` exported? Does your LDAP server require authentication to retrieve the user keys?

Comment: And also, does `ls -Z /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-wrapper` indicate that it has the correct SELinux context?

Comment: @user1686 I added that info to my question.  Running as root the wrapper successfully retrieves the `userx`'s key from the LDAP server **w/o the need for explicit authentication**. Exporting that variables does **not** alter this. Unfortunately, there is no log on ldap queries I can find beyond the one on `/var/log/secure` where I see that `failed status 255`. `ldap.conf` does specify a log file `/var/log/openssh-ldap.log` and a loglevel of `debug`, yet that file is not even created.

Comment: Finally, I disabled SELinux and the problem disappeared. So, SEL seemed indeed to be the culprit, but I wasn't able to find the proper SEL configuration to have the LDAP connection working.

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7 this script should be run as the user "nobody" by default.

I suspect you've changed to run it as root, AND SELinux has got itself involved because of the increased privs.

---

For future readers, I had bad permissions of 600 on /etc/openldap/cacert.pem

I identified this by running:

```
su nobody -s /bin/bash -c "strace   /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-ldap-helper -s root -v "
```

and hidden in the output was:

```
open("/etc/openldap/cacert.pem", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The fix was `sudo chmod 644 /etc/openldap/cacert.pem`